# Limit amount of files user can select in QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

Here the code:

```
dialog = new QFileDialog(this);
dialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(currentChanged(const QString&)),
    this, SLOT(dialogSelectionChanged(const QString&)));

void MainWindow::dialogSelectionChanged(const QString& file)
{
    QStringList selected = dialog->selectedFiles();
}
```

The problem is that

- `fileSelected(const QString&)` and `filesSelected(const QStringList&)` emitted only after I press 'Open' button.
- `currentChanged(const QString&)` passes only newly selected file
- and `selectedFiles()` returns me in that case files that were selected at previous step. Probably dialog updates files after it emits `currentChanged(const QString&)`.

That is why I don't know how to trace currently selected files.
Another problem is that I don't know so far how to cancel selection of last selected file if user exceeds limit of allowed selections.

I have seen couple of examples where people implement custom features either with `QProxyModel` or with custom implementation of `QFileDialog` but I'm not sure what will fit my needs best.

Comment: Did you try overriding `selectFile(const QString& filename)`? Might be the one you are looking for.

Comment: From the documentation it does not look like that is a virtual function

Comment: It's not, I have checked sources. Additionally, this method is not used in implementation, that just part of user API, not more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you're willing to accept a shameless hack :-)

Assuming the following code...

```
QFileDialog fd;
```

Inspecting `fd` using `fd.findChildren<QListView *>()` reveals that it has two children that either are or inherit from `QListView`...

1. QListView named listView
2. QSidebar named sidebar

(where QSidebar is private to Qt).

Working on the assumption that the `QListView` named `listView` is the widget of interest you can connect a callback to its selection model...

```
QFileDialog fd;
for (const auto &i: fd.findChildren<QListView *>("listView")) {
  auto *sm = i->selectionModel();
  QObject::connect(sm, &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,
                   [sm](const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
                     {

                       /*
                        * Here we pass a hard-coded max selected items
                        * value of 5 to the real callback/slot.
                        */
                       handle_selection_updated(5, sm, selected, deselected);
                     });
}
```

Here `handle_selection_updated` has the following definition...

```
void handle_selection_updated (int selection_max, QItemSelectionModel *sm,
                               const QItemSelection &selected,
                               const QItemSelection &deselected)
{

  /*
   * We need to remember the last valid selection.  The following
   * is declared static in this simple case but would generally be
   * a class member in `real' code.
   */
  static QItemSelection last_selected;

  /*
   * Because we update the selection model `sm' from within this
   * slot this function will recurse which will cause problems if
   * we don't detect it and take appropriate action.
   */
  static bool recursing = false;
  if (recursing)
    return;

  /*
   * If the number of rows selected is greater than the value
   * specified by `selection_max' then revert to the last valid
   * selection as specified by `last_selected'.
   */
  if (sm->selectedRows().size() > selection_max) {

    /*
     * The following call to QItemSelectionModel::clearSelection
     * will result in a recursive call to this function.  Set
     * `recursing' to true to catch this and avoid associated
     * problems.
     */
    recursing = true;

    /*
     * Now clear the selection and reset it to the items from
     * `last_selected'.
     */
    sm->clearSelection();
    for (const auto &i: last_selected.indexes()) {
      sm->select(i, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
    }
    recursing = false;
  }

  /*
   * Update `last_selected'.
   */
  last_selected = sm->selection();
}
```

I've only tested the above code briefly but it appears to behave in the manner required.

Answer (score 2):

there is no method for that but as soon as your client is done with the selection you can validate the operation by calling the method [selectedFiles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#selectedFiles)

is the size of that QStringList is greater than your constrain you can abort the operation and show some error msg.

like

```
void MainWindow::dialogSelectionChanged(const QString& file)
{
    QStringList selected = dialog->selectedFiles();
    if(selected.size()>LIMIT)
    {
        showErrorMsg("some helpful mesage");
    }

}
```

Comment: That what I'm going to use if won't find a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: there is no other, unless you write your own Dialog ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯